# Id used to find object from db is changing on request

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WY3TI.png) building app on express and mongoose mongodb. when  trying to get to /musics/:id to get to details page app is sending me to correct page and it is crashing because id is changed

```
    app.get("/musics/:id", async (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.params);
  const { id } = req.params;
  const music = await Music.findById(id);
  res.render("./music/edit", { music });
});
```

here is error

```
    DATABASE CONNECTED!
{ id: '625d0fb066f8544535a2466d' }
{ id: 'Roboto-Regular.ttf' }
C:\Users\akbar\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\MusicApp2.0\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4715
  const castError = new CastError();
                    ^

CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "Roboto-Regular.ttf" (type string) at path "_id" for model "Music"
    at model.Query.exec (C:\Users\akbar\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\MusicApp2.0\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4715:21)
    at model.Query.Query.then (C:\Users\akbar\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\MusicApp2.0\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4814:15)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
  messageFormat: undefined,
  stringValue: '"Roboto-Regular.ttf"',
  kind: 'ObjectId',
  value: 'Roboto-Regular.ttf',
  path: '_id',
  reason: BSONTypeError: Argument passed in must be a string of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters or an integer
```

[here source code](https://github.com/AkbarjonAbdukarimov/MusicApp2.0.git)

Comment: this is a route
app.get("/musics/:id", async (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.params);
  const { id } = req.params;
  const music = await Music.findById(id);
  res.render("./music/edit", { music });
});

Comment: here is the error log
DATABASE CONNECTED!
{ id: '625d0fb066f8544535a2466d' }
{ id: 'Roboto-Regular.ttf' }
C:\Users\akbar\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\MusicApp2.0\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4715
  const castError = new CastError();
                    ^

CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "Roboto-Regular.ttf" (type string) at path "_id" for model "Music"

Comment: Can you please add your code in the question instead of comment.

Comment: yes i did u can see screenshot too

Comment: The id is not "changing", you are getting another request to `/musics/Roboto-Regular.ttf`, presumably from one of your CSS files. Either that's an incorrect URL that you should fix, or it's a valid one and you need to change your route to manage that.

Comment: ok will try to change the route

Comment: @AkbarjonAbdukarimov you should deal with serving static assets (app.use(express.static(....))), I think that'll fix your error

Comment: @Joshua I am serving static files but it is not working

Answer (score 1):

as suggested in comments changing route url helped

```
app.get("/musics/:id/details", async (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.params;
  const music = await Music.findById(id);
  res.render("./music/edit", { music });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a different function

```
await Music.findOne({_id: id})
```

Change

```
res.render("./music/edit", { music });
```

To

```
res.render("music/edit", { music });
```